# <div ui-view=""> </div> Works fine in Chrome but it is completely empty on Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `ui.router` in my angular application with `<div ui-view="">   </div>`.

Everything works fine on Google Chrome but it is completely empty on Internet Explorer.

Below is a picture showing the problem and comparison between Internet Explorer and Chrome.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove the `=""` after the `ui-view` directive?

Comment: I removed it but the problem still persists.

Comment: What is your IE version?

Comment: Is there any console error?

Comment: There must be some other error occurring in IE then. We make heavy use of `ui.router` and have never had an issue with IE.

Comment: It is Internet Explorer 11 and my angular version is 1.5 . There is no error on my console.

Comment: There has to be something wrong, Start debugging, is application booting? Use breakpoints, ensure the route is triggered, follow the route through to ui-router and see why its not populating it. I'm quiet confident its not booting the applicaiton or not booting the route. Start isolating, make a plunker to replicate.